# How do I format my plist array to look nice in a tablecell?

Tags: swift

I have some saved plist data that outputs in my tableCell like this:

```
[findameeting_app.FavoriteLocation(name: "Alcoholics Anon Meeting", address: "2532 Hampton Glen ct, Matthews Nc", latitude: 33.46996, longitude: -111.9845152)]
```

I'm not sure how to format the decoded array can look normal in a tableCell. Like perhaps just showing the title of the meeting and address under it?

```
 import UIKit

class favoritesListController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableData = [String]()
    //writing data

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realpath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("Favorites.plist")

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: realpath)
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            do {
                let favoriteLocationsArray = try decoder.decode(Array<FavoriteLocation>.self, from: data)
                // This is your data ready to use
                print(favoriteLocationsArray)


                tableData = ["\(favoriteLocationsArray)"] // outputting here.


            } catch  {
                // Handle error
            }

        } catch  {
            // Handle error
        }

    }



    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(tableData.count)
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return(cell)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a table view outlet and connect it in Interface Builder

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

---

2) Connect also `dataSource` and `delegate` of the table view in IB

---

3) Replace

```
var tableData = [String]()
```

with

```
var tableData = [FavoriteLocation]()
```

---

4) Replace

```
let favoriteLocationsArray = try decoder.decode(Array<FavoriteLocation>.self, from: data)
```

with

```
self.tableData = try decoder.decode(Array<FavoriteLocation>.self, from: data)
```

---

5) Replace

```
tableData = ["\(favoriteLocationsArray)"] // outputting here.
```

with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

6) Replace

```
cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
```

with (the table cell style must be set accordingly to enable detailTextLabel)

```
cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row].name
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row].address
```

---

And remove all parentheses after return e.g. `return(cell)`. `return` is **not** a function.